# JQuery: determine if certain IDed element is the first with a certain class?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="welcome" class="right"></div>
<div id="visit_us" class="right"></div>
<div id="our_products" class="right"></div>
```

A function is passed an ID and I need to know if it is the first first element that has the class "right". So "welcome" would be true, while the others would be false.
I thought this might do it:

```
function highlightElement(el){
   $(el + ":eq(.right:first)")
}
```

but no dice (or at least it doesn't appear to be doing it correctly). Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$(el).is('.right:first')
```

probably in a `if` statement

```
if($(el).is('.right:first')){
    console.log('is first')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BejRr/)

*Note: You need to pass an id selector here, else need to prefix `#`*

Comment: Thank you. this is what I needed. And thanks to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".right:first");
```

should do it

This will let you add whatever highlighting styles you want directly on the element returned.

Ex:

```
$(".right:first").addClass("highlighterClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the problem is that `el` still needs the id indicator (`#`) for the selector to work:

```
function highlightElement(el){
   $("#" + el + ":eq(.right:first)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could match these with the `id` of the first element :

```
this.id === $(".right:first").attr("id")
```

(One of the many ways of doing it)

Full code :

```
function highlightElement(el){
   alert(el === $(".right:first").attr("id")) //or just hard-code the id! :)
}
```

This will return `true` if the id's match :)

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/LZWJa/